# Has a correlation between sleep apnea and grinding of teeth been identified or ruled out?

Tags: dentistry, correlation, sleep-apnea

Disclaimer: I have no formal education in any medical field.

[Jaw position has been demonstrated to be a modulating factor in sleep apnea](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/04/190416093729.htm). Has any investigation been conducted to consider the possible relationship between grinding one's teeth and sleep apnea?

Comment: Jaw position in regard to sleep apnoea is not a new idea. In fact [mandibular advancement devices](https://britishsnoring.co.uk/shop/mandibular_advancement_devices_MADs.php) were recommended to me years ago before moving me on to a CPAP machine. (See [my answer to your related question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/19178))

Comment: I removed the word "recently". What I'm asking about in my question relates specifically to "grinding one's teeth". For example, if someone grinds their teeth does that indicate that they should be tested for sleep apnea? Might addressing grinding might apnea go away? IE: Maybe quitting caffeine consumption?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true.
A relationship does exist between grinding the teeth and sleep apnea.
The term bruxism(sleep bruxism) is used for grinding the teeth during sleep at night.
In a [study](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11325-014-0953-5) it was seen that the patients with obstructive sleep apnea syndrome also demonstrated with sleep bruxism.
Interestingly treating the sleep apnea syndrome may also prevent sleep bruxism.[reference](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11325-014-0953-5)

Another good [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1389945702001302) you may refer, wherein there was a study done proving this relation.